# Undeclared addition for two arrays in numba

Tags: python, numba

I have this simple program that adds two arrays using `numba`:

```
import numpy
import numba

@numba.jit(
    numba.void(numba.float64[:], numba.float64[:], numba.float64[:]),
    nopython=True)
def add(c, a, b):
    c[:] = a[:] + b[:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = numpy.arange(10000) * 1.0
    b = numpy.arange(10000) * 1.0
    c = numpy.zeros_like(a)
    add(c, a, b)
    print(c)
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error from the JIT compiler:

```
numba.typeinfer.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Undeclared +(array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, A))
```

Is there a way to make it work, or should I be using `guvectorize()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to check your `numba` version, there are some [cool, new features](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.20.0/release-notes.html#version-0-19-0) for working with arrays since 0.19.1. Moreover, `numba` isn't necessarily the way-to-go for simple operations that can be vectorised so easily.

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit
def add_numba(c, a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

def add_no_numba(c, a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print numba.__version__

    a = np.arange(10000, dtype=np.float64)
    b = np.arange(10000, dtype=np.float64)

    # numba
    c = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=np.float64)
    %timeit add_numba(c, a, b)
    print add_numba(c, a, b)

    # no numba
    c = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=np.float64)
    %timeit add_no_numba(c, a, b)
    print add_no_numba(c, a, b)

>> 0.19.1 
>> 10000 loops, best of 3: 24.8 µs per loop
>> [  0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00  ...,    1.99980000e+04]
>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 7.44 µs per loop
>> [  0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00  ...,    1.99980000e+04]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. As for the code in the question, it's just an MWE to illustrate the problem.